# Uploading a PDF file in Angular

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular5

I've been trying to save a PDF file to the assets folder in Angular.

I get this file through a file input in a form like this

```
onFileChange($event) {
    this.file = $event.target.files[0]; // <--- File Object for future use.
    this.homebrew.controls['file'].setValue(this.file ? this.file.name : ''); // <-- Set Value for Validation
```

My question is: how do I save this to the assets folder in my project for future use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a server for this, angular alone won't cut it. Once you have a server, don't upload to the assets folder though, it's meant for static files only and is wiped everytime you publish a new version of your app.

Comment: There are several tutorials about setting up a server for that, out there, just search "nodejs upload file".

Comment: Thanks for the help! I allready have a backend running so it should not be a problem